How to use self-singed certificates on DDG iOS browser
I cannot access a local website I built with Django on my iPhone using DuckDuckGo browser because it does not trust the self singed certificate even though I manually installed it on my iPhone. The error message that I get says:
"The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be "192.168.1.128" which could put your confidential information at risk.”
I used mkcert on my macBook to generate the certificate, uploaded it to the “server” (everything is running locally on my macBook) and installed it on my iPhone. When using Safari everything is working fine. The certificate is a .pem file.
After researching the internet, I tried to follow these instructions on apple.stackexchange.com - but I don’t have the option to "Enable full trust for root certificates" for the newly-installed certificate as it is shown here on support.apple.com.
Edit: Accessing the local website using DDG on my macBook is working without any issues.

This question isn't a programming question but one about configuring certificates on specific OS / browser and is hence off-topic for this site.
